# SVG paths in Inkscape aren't modified when I stretch

Tags: svg, inkscape

We are using Inkscape basically as a means to create SVGs. Once done, we open the SVG as an XML file and extract the paths (the d-attributes).

However I notice that if we resize/stretch the entire drawing (all paths in a single group) the paths themselves are left unchanged. All that's happening in the XML is Inkscape is applying a **transform** on the g node container.

Is there a way make to make the stretch apply to the individual paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turns out to be simple: remove the grouping. This removes the g node and any stretching is applied to each individual path.